# Optimal way to extract value from adjacent node in a nested XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, generics, nested, nodes

I currently have an interesting multi-layer nested XML that I want to extract value from using Java.

All of the nodes in this XML have generic tags, and each tag has generic keyword.

The value I want to extract is many layers deep, and the way to identify it is not by its keyword, which is a generic keyword "NumericalValue" (there are many node with the same keyword).

There is a node above it (same layer but is >= 1 node above it) that has a generic keyword "WordRepresentation" (there are many node withe a same keyword) and a value "Customer ID."  We know for certain that if the value "Customer ID" exists, one or more nodes below, we will find the keyword "NumericalValue" and the value.

So the logic to extract the value I want is: first unwrap the nested XML until I find the level containing the value "Customer ID," then somehow make a note of that level and in the same level, keep navigating to the next node until I find the keyword "NumericValue," and record the value.

Is there a good way or a good tool to search within a nested XML for a specific value and to navigate within the same level for a second search?

Below is an example of the XML:

```
<xml>
<layer 1>
    <layer 2>
    </layer 2>
    <layer 2>
         <layer 3>
              <layer 4>
                   <layer 5>
                        <layer 6>
                             <layer 7 keyword=WordRepresentaion>
                                  <Value>Customer ID</Value>
                             </layer 7>
                             ...
                             <layer 7 keyword=NumbericalValue>
                                  <Value>453</Value>
                             </layer7>
                             ...

                        </layer 6>

                   </layer 5>
              </layer 4>
         </layer 3>


    </layer 2>
    ...

    ...
    <layer 2>
    </layer 2>
    <layer 2>
    </layer 2>
</layer 1>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand exactly what you're trying to do but you can use `jsoup` to parse the XML. Here is an example:

```
    String xml = "<xml>\n<layer 1>\n    <layer 2>\n    </layer 2>\n    <layer 2>\n         <layer 3>\n              <layer 4>\n                   <layer 5>\n                        <layer 6>\n                             <layer 7 keyword=WordRepresentaion>\n                                  <Value>Customer ID</Value>\n                             </layer 7>\n                             <layer 7 keyword=NumbericalValue>\n                                  <Value>453</Value>\n                             </layer7>\n                        </layer 6>\n\n                   </layer 5>\n              </layer 4>\n         </layer 3>\n    </layer 2>\n    <layer 2>\n    </layer 2>\n    <layer 2>\n    </layer 2>\n</layer 1>\n</xml>";
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(xml);

    Elements elms = doc.select("Value:contains(Customer ID)"); // get all the elements that are about the searched one
    if (elms.size() > 0) {
        Element wrapper = elms.first().parent(); // get the first one's parent
        Element layer = wrapper.parent();
        Elements layerChildren = layer.getElementsByIndexGreaterThan(wrapper.elementSiblingIndex()); // get all elements in the layer that are below the reference element
        for (Element e : layerChildren) {
            if (e.attr("keyword").equals("NumbericalValue")) { // check to see if this is the searched element.
                System.out.println("Got the element:\n" + e.outerHtml());
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is another approach:

```
    Elements els = doc.select("[keyword=NumbericalValue]");

    for (Element e : els) {
        int index = e.siblingIndex();
        Elements elementsAbove = e.parent().getElementsByIndexLessThan(index);
        for (Element above : elementsAbove) {
            // Check if this node has an inner node with the value "Customer ID"
            if (above.select("Value:contains(Customer ID)").size() > 0) {
                System.out.println("FOUND A MATCH:\n" + e.outerHtml());
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this example all the `keyword= NumbericalValue` are selected and inside the loop we're looking at the element above it to see if they have their value set to `Customer ID`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Just to clarify a bit, I am trying to extract the value of a node with the keyword "NumericalValue".  But since there are many node with that keyword, I have to look one or more nodes above it in the same level, to see if there is another node with the value "Customer ID."

Comment: @000000000000000000000 I think that the example code in my answer does that. Another approach will be to search directly for `keyword  =NumericalValue` nodes and look at the nodes above it to see if they have the value `Customer ID`. I will post an example that does this shortly.